# A simple question related to binomial distribution (the expected value of a nested binomial random variable)

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Assume that $X\sim Binomial(n,p)$.
Also, assume that $Y\sim Binomial(n+X,p)$. We are interested in computing the expected value of $Y$, i.e., $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Y]$.

**Question:** Why is the following solution incorrect?

We have:
$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Y] = (n+X)p$$

We take another expectation from both sides:
$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Y]] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Y] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[(n+X)p]=(n+\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X])p = (n+np)p$$

Comment: The first line doesn't make sense : the right hand side is a non-degenerate random variable (i.e. it takes at least two different values with non-zero probability) but the left hand side is a fixed real number.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation is a linear form wrt to '+, const*, so $$\mathbb E(n + p X)= \mathbb E(n) + \mathbb E( p X) = n + p\mathbb E(X)  = n + p^2 n  $$